# Java Replace String with two (or more) expressions

Tags: java, regex, replace, str-replace

I want to replace this strings: 
- `http://fitness.com/gorilla-bumpers` - `http://www.fitness.com/gorilla-bumpers` with the expression "Product: gorilla-bumpers".

I have the following code:

```
final String url = eElement.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0).getTextContent();
final String qty = eElement.getElementsByTagName("quantity").item(0).getTextContent();
//I 've got "url" and "qty" values from Xml after parsing it

String product = url.replace("http://fitness.com/", "Product: ");           
System.out.println(product + " was added to the cart with Qty = " + qty);
```

How can I add one more replacement in Java? 
Will be appreciate for several variants providing. Thank you

Comment: how about: by writing a second call to the replace method?

Comment: How about `url.replace("http://fitness.com/", "Product: ").replace("","").replace....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it like:

```
String product = url.replace( "http://fitness.com/", "Product: " ).replace( "http://www.fitness.com/", "Product: " );
```

Also you can try regexes since `.replaceAll` function takes regex

```
String product = url.replaceAll( "http:.*\/", "Product: " );
```

Note that I'm not an expert on regexes, you should create your own. This one replaces every http://BLABLA/ strings

Comment: I've added another thing for you, you can try it as well

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
final String url = eElement.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0).getTextContent();
final String qty = eElement.getElementsByTagName("quantity").item(0).getTextContent();

String product = url.replace("http://fitness.com/", "Product: ")
                .replace("http://www.fitness.com/", "Product: ");
        System.out.println(product + " was added to the cart with Qty = " + qty);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you Suggest any other variants of implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
final String url = eElement.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0).getTextContent();
final String qty = eElement.getElementsByTagName("quantity").item(0).getTextContent();

String product = url.replaceAll("http://fitness.com/", "Product: ").replaceAll("http://www.fitness.com/", "Product: ");

System.out.println(product + " was added to the cart with Qty = " + qty);
```

Comment: but don't you think, your example will only replace this: `http://fitness.com/`?
But not this: `http://www.fitness.com/`

And I need to replace both

Comment: @EvgEvg I have updated my answer. I am sorry, I didn't read the question correctly.